# ZF2- Dynamic base route

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-route

I'm trying to create a dynamic route in a ZF2 project. It will be something like "domain.com/companyurl/products". The company url is dynamic. I did it:

```
'company' => array(
     'type' => 'Segment',
     'options' => array(
         'route' => '[/:company]',
         'defaults' => array(
             'controller' => 'IndexController',
             'action'     => 'index',
          ),
      ),
      'may_terminate' => true,
      'child_routes' => array(
          ...
      ),

 ),
```

But I always have to pass the company parameter in a route.

```
$this->url('company/products', array('company' => 'companyurl'));
```

Is there some way to specify a base route at the runtime, like a base url, then all route will follow it? Something like this:

```
$this->url('products');
```

or

```
$this->url('company/products');
```

In the both cases I already specified the base route value.

I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: You could subclass the url view helper (Zend\View\Helper\Url) to add the company url in automatically for all urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `$reuseRouteParams` option that you can use in the URL helper:

```
$this->url($name, $params, $options,$reuseMatchedParameters);
```

If you set this to true it will reuse the previous route match value of `companyUrl`.

You can read more on this in the docs [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html).